# Auto click on button (In Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, button, click

In this code:

```
<div id="tagsdiv-post_tag" class="postbox " >
<div class="inside">

<div class="tagsdiv" id="post_tag">
    <div class="jaxtag">
        <div class="ajaxtag hide-if-no-js">
        <p><input type="text" id="new-tag-post_tag" name="newtag[post_tag]" class="newtag form-input-tip" size="16" autocomplete="off" value="" />
        <input type="button" class="button tagadd" value="Add" tabindex="3" /></p>
    </div>
        </div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want auto click on this button :

```
<input type="button" class="button tagadd" value="Add" tabindex="3" />
```

I tried with this code :

```
$(".ajaxtag input.button").click();
```

but it's not working.
Thats code get from Wordpress admin post page.

Comment: Have you added this button after the page has been completely loaded ? (= have you added this button dynamically ?)

Comment: @Romain Guidoux This is souce code from Tags insert in wordpress admin post page.

Comment: ok. Perhaps it is added dynamically, try the live() method (see my answer).
And don't forget to execute it that way : `$(function() { your code here });`

Answer (score 2):

Try attaching an ID to the button, using jQuery to search the button by id, and click it... Only when the entire site is loaded. **Example below.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     document.getElementById('ButtonId').click(); 
});
```

where 'ButtonId' is the ID of the button you want to click

Try attaching something to your button though, its not doing anything for now.

Comment: @Nulled: If you can't change the code, what on earth do you expect to do? "How can I change this code to do X, without changing the code?"

Comment: Is the item generated by a plugin, or theme. It is possible to change the code, unless ur using the wordpress.com free version

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ajaxtag input.button").trigger('click');
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that your code does work - see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBCw7/2/) as an example. Note that you need to put this code in the onload event, using `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: The code should work... you should see an alert when the page loads (and when you click the button).

Comment: @Nulled: Where on earth did Wordpress come into this? Your question does not mention it even once.

Comment: @James: The OP wants the button to be clicked automatically, not to set a handler for when the user clicks it.

Comment: @Tomalak - The button is clicked automatically, I just added the handler so that you see something happen when the click event is triggered.

Comment: @James: Where is it clicked automatically?

Comment: @Tomalak - Oh dear :( I didn't save the fiddle in it's finished state. Have a look now, that is what I intended.

Comment: @James: You need to post the new URL. There is one URL per fiddle.

Comment: @Tomalak - Not my day today apparently! Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/mBCw7/2/

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Ok I add this info to my Q.

Comment: @James: Better! Perhaps the answer should be updated with this link.

Comment: @James: Now my next comment is that this isn't his code, so "your code does work" doesn't seem right. For one, you have a DOM-onload wrapper whereas the OP has given no indication of this.

Comment: @Tomalak - Agreed. What do you think of this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/mBCw7/3/

Comment: @James: It's the same. You have the "onLoad" wrapper specified in jsfiddle.net. _This_ is the OP's code, which as you can see [does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/GuaCt/).

Comment: @Tomalak - I give up! Feel free to put that downvote back (I'm assuming it was you). I deserve it after all that.

Comment: @James: The solution's correct; just explain that you need the DOM-onLoad wrapper to make it work!